# Custom Rest API giving 500 Error on server while working on local perfectly

Tags: php, rest, magento

We have added Custom Rest API module for,

files we haved added and its path 
    `app\code\local\Restapi\...`

and
    `app\etc\modules\Restapi_mymodule` respectively,

now issue is,

while calling this API

```
`http://domainname.com/api/rest/offers?module=home_screen`
```

its working on localhost perfectly,

and on live server its giving

```
 `NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://theethnicwear.com/api/rest/offers?module=home_screen`
```

Comment: Can you supply the code as well please?

Comment: are you using short codes? means <? ?> or <?php ?> ?

Comment: Have you looked at the error logs on the server?

Answer (score 1):

I was having same issue some days back, It's because my server was not allowing `short_open_tag` as short tags are deprecated. So I just changed `<?` to `<?php`.

It works for me.

[For more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Answer (score 0):

I would follow up with what AP said as a known cause between production server and local dev because you sometime your local dev might not have the same configuration as production (depending on how you set it up unless you built it 1:1 or clone a perfect vagrant...)

Also 500 errors can be debugged also via `php5-fpm-error.log` on the server or php error log files (as the name of the log can vary). Those are the known locations that you should check if you want to debug your code for 500 as it will likely tell you first off if your code is at fault or some other thing might be at fault